# Writing a post receive script for windows

Tags: git, web-services, windows-server-2012

I am currently using bonobo git web server for 2012. I want to write a post-recieve hook so that I can check my repo into the active directory of my website.
I declare my post-receive script like this

```
  #!/bin/sh
  GIT_WORK_TREE=C:/Domains/Demo.com git checkout -f
```

When I push with changes to my git server it should now checkout the contents of my repo into the the Domains/Demo Folder. After I change a small thing and commit to the webserver, I check the directory of Demo.com , and see if there is any contents. Sadly there is none. Is there a way to know if the script is running? Is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test whether your `post-receive` hook gets executed by adding some `echo` statements. From the [`githooks` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#post-receive):

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to `git send-pack` on the other end, so you can simply `echo` messages for the user.

Furthermore I would suggest to use the `--work-tree` option instead of the `GIT_WORKING_TREE` environment variable. A modified version of your script would look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree="C:/Domains/Demo.com" checkout -f
```

Comment: I try to do git work-tree="C:/Domains/.." It just spits out the usage in the cmd.

Comment: You have to use `git --work-tree` not `git work-tree`. What do you mean with "it spits out the usage in the cmd"?

Comment: Sorry I do use git --work-tree="Directory" yet the system still seems to think its not a command. I am using the bash emulation script on windows.

Comment: Due to the command being a native git command you can try to execute it as a bat windows script. Maybe that does the trick.